# Matlab - Discrete values of rho every 10 degrees of object margin in polar coordinates

Tags: matlab, image-processing, polar-coordinates

I have shapes of letters represented in polar coordinates. The centroid of the shape equals the center of the polar representation.  **I need the values of rho every 10 degrees of the object's outer margin**.

Examples of shapes in polar coordinates I have:

[image: letter d uppercase]
[image: letter m lowercase]

I have 2 problems I can't solve:

1. Matlab's `[theta,rho]=cart2pol(x,y)` theta doesn't return the angles in degrees.  When plotting the object with `polar(theta,rho)` the object is well represented, but I don't understand what's the equivalence between matlab's theta value and each angle in degrees.
2. As the margin is in discrete, probably I won't have a margin point for every angle I need, so I need a way to get the nearest margin point for a given angle (and the farthest point for the letters with interior and exterior margin).

Comment: 1. It's radial coordinates, not degrees! Try `theta_d = theta*180/pi`

Comment: @StewieGriffin, It is a simple solution, but it's probably still worth writing up as an answer so the question is marked

Comment: ... or use `rad2deg`.